# Change text with icon in css

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have number 1 that i want to change with font awsome with css.

I have this code to replace:

```
#label_13_5_0  span {
  display: none;
}
#label_13_5_0:after {
  content: "hi";
}
```

First problem: 1 is still there. Like you can see on this pic: [see prt sc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL00U.png)

Second problem i want to change "hi" with icon:

```
class="fa fa-star"
```

https://fontawesome.com/icons/star?style=regular

Comment: Well... there is no markup in your question. My guess is the `1` is probably not in the hidden `<span>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#label_13_5_0 span {
  display: none !important;
}
#label_13_5_0:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005";
   }
```

Comment: the icon now works: thank you; but the "1" is still there; does not disapear:/

Comment: i want to see your html , pls capture